# How to auto call in pjsua?

Tags: sip, pjsip

I use pjsua as an ip-phone. I want to auto call in pjsua. I checked the manual and notice that an option named auto answer is used for auto answer.
can I auto call with pjsua?

Comment: What do you mean by auto call? You want pjsua to automatically dial out an uri? Based on what event?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I mean call and after 10 seconds quit from pjsua. I dial sip:**@*** and on the other side it answer. I set duration on 10 seconds, after call ends, pjsua wait until I press "q" button to quit from it. I want quit automatically.

Comment: Pjsua cannot do that by default. You can write an application using the APIs provided by pjsua and implement it.

Comment: Optionally you can download the source, slightly modify it and build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your reply,

I run pjsua in rc.local as below:

`(sleep 20; echo q) | ./pjsua --config-file config.cfg sip:**@*****`

After 20 seconds, it quit automatically.
This link help me:http://aminastaneh.net/2012-05-06/fun-with-command-line-sip.html

Sorry, maybe I should say that my os that used as ip-phone is vyatta.

Comment: How did you make that auto call. I need pjsua to call to number automatically.? What should I include in config file for it